# Dynamically load 5 buttons on 1 row

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I'm having some difficulties with this tablelayout which should create a new Row after 5 buttons. It also crashes when i add button.setText(lesson.getId());

LesSelectionActivity.java

```
    public static final int LESSON_ROW_COUNT = 5;

    public void setButtonLessons() {

    //draw LesSelection
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drumles);

    TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.les_select_layout);

    int buttonIdCounter = 0;
    for (Lesson lesson : getArrayLesson()) {
        int columnCounter = 0;

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
        tr.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.addView(tr);

            if (columnCounter % LESSON_ROW_COUNT == 0) {
                tr = new TableRow(this);
                params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
                tr.setLayoutParams(params);
                layout.addView(tr);
            }

            Button button = new Button(this);

            button.setId(buttonIdCounter);

          //button.setText(lesson.getId());

            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonsoranje);
            TableRow.LayoutParams paramsRow = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            paramsRow.column = columnCounter % LESSON_ROW_COUNT;
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;


            tr.addView(button);

            buttonIdCounter++;
            columnCounter = (columnCounter + 1) % LESSON_ROW_COUNT;
        }

    }
```

So, why does setText doesn't work but setBackgroundResource does? (note that i have "//" it because it's not working now, the awnser is not "remove //")

Why is there only 1 button per row?

Comment: I have fixed it, the "for (Lesson lesson : getArrayLesson()) {" was set up to high, placed it down just above the if, then it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming `lesson.getId();` returns an integer value of id. `setText()` needs a String parameter. You need to do `button.setText(String.valueOf(lesson.getId()));`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it did! I don't understand why it has to be a string suddenly, but glad this problem is solved. There is still the other problem, why is there only 1 button per row?